# Estimation of low bounde of gradient of eigenfunction on circle .

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Consider the eigenvalue problem 
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = \lambda u    ~~~~~~~~x\in \Omega \\
u|_{\partial \Omega}=0
\end{cases}
when $\Omega$ is a circle, I see a picture from [this](https://chebfun.org/examples/disk/Eigenfunctions.html) as following
[image]

which is the picture of first eigenfunction on unit circle. Denote the first eigenfunction as $\varphi$, then ,seemly ,the $|\nabla \varphi|$ has a low boundary. In fact, I always think $|\nabla \varphi|\rightarrow 0$ when $x\rightarrow \partial \Omega$. But seemly, I am wrong.  So, I want some reference about the low bound of $|\nabla \varphi|$.  But only upper bound  I can find it.  Who can help me ,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Hopf lemma (which you can find for instance in Evan's book) prevents this.
Because we know that the first eigenfunction is positive, we have
$$ -\Delta u \geq 0, x \in \Omega$$
$$ u = 0 , x \in \partial \Omega$$

So if the boundary of $\Omega$ is $C^2$ (which is the case for the circle), Hopf lemma tels you that
$$\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial n} < 0 , \forall x \in \partial \Omega$$
where $n$ is the outer normal.

Because of the Dirichlet boundary conditions, the tangent derivative vanishes at the boundary so 
$$ | \nabla u(x) | = |\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial n}| > 0 , \forall x \in \partial \Omega $$

In the particular case of the circle, you can compute the solution explicitly:
$$u(x) = a J_0(\frac{\nu_0}{R} |x| )$$
where a is an arbitrary non-zero constant and $\nu_0$ is the first zero of the Bessel function $J_0$.
then $$\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial n} = \frac{a\nu_0}{R} J_0'(\nu_0) \not = 0$$